# Dependency injection of CustomFieldManager

Tags: java, dependency-injection, jira-plugin

I get the error message saying no bean found whenever I try to use dependency inject a CustomFieldManager. I have the component import in my atlassian-plugin.xml and this works for IssueManager but not for CustomFieldManager. I have the same problem when trying to inject the JiraAuthenticationContext.

atlassian-plugin.xml component imports:

`<component-import key="issueManager" interface="com.atlassian.jira.issue.IssueManager" filter=""/>
  <component-import key="customFieldManager" interface="com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager" filter=""/>
  <component-import key="jiraAuthenticationContext" interface="com.atlassian.jira.security.JiraAuthenticationContext" filter=""/>`

error message:

`com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 2 of type [com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager]: : No unique bean of type [com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager] is defined: Unsatisfied dependency of type [interface com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager]: expected at least 1 matching bean; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No unique bean of type [com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager] is defined: Unsatisfied dependency of type [interface com.atlassian.jira.issue.CustomFieldManager]: expected at least 1 matching bean`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this issue by running `atlas-clean`.